# Three.js animated color change control

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I'm struggling to apply a correct tint color to this animation in Three.js. Even if I apply correct tint color eg: #008080 the actual color is not green just blue or something. It looks like there is some calculation of the highlight color. How do I switch it off or control it?

```
  const PARTICLE_SIZE = 1;
  const textureAttr = {
    resolution: 64,
    radius: 32,
    color: '#008080'
  };
```

Working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/6cq1re9o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color was modified by the fragment shader:

```
// noise RGB values
float r = 1. - 2.0 * noise;
float g = 0.0;
float b = 1. - 1.0 * noise;
vec3 foo = vec3(r*2.0, g, b*1.5);

// calculate a new color using the above noise
gl_FragColor = vec4( foo, 1.0 ) * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
```

---

Since you just want the provided hex color, just uncomment and use this bit:

```
// grab the textel
gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, vec2(pos.x, pos.y) );
// or just use the noisy bit without the noise
// gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
```

texture2D docs [here](http://www.shaderific.com/glsl-functions). It simply returns a color of a point on a texture.

Check it out in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zqf5kwg/1/).

If you want to "control" it, then you'd need to modify the `foo` RGB color which is used as noise.

---

This may be only my opinion, but this webpack blob is highly unreadable. Next time please try making a [minimal example focusing only on the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Piotr, your example looks broken? The animation is no longer smooth and there are squares rather than dots?

Comment: Ok, I've got it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/6mqo2usj/2/ Thanks for your help